# Multiple Kubernetes authorization modules checked in sequence, how?

Tags: kubernetes, authorization

From the Kubernetes [documentation on authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#determine-whether-a-request-is-allowed-or-denied) it states that:

> When multiple authorization modules are configured, each is checked in sequence. If any authorizer approves or denies a request, that decision is immediately returned and no other authorizer is consulted. If all modules have no opinion on the request, then the request is denied. A deny returns an HTTP status code 403.

I am now writing a custom webhook for authorization and I would want the logic to fallback to RBAC for a few cases - i.e. have my webhook respond with what the documentation refers to as "no opinion". The documentation however only details how to approve or deny a request and doesn't come back to this third option which seems essential for having multiple authorization modules checked in sequence. How would I best in the context of my webhook respond with "I have no opinion on this request, please pass it on to the next authorizer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how multiple `AuthorizationModule` work from kubernetes official doc.

So I check the source code of apiserver, it create a combine `authorizer.Authorizer` by `union.New(authorizers...)`, from `union` source I find the answer:

> The union authorizer iterates over each subauthorizer and returns the first decision that is either an Allow decision or a Deny decision. If a subauthorizer returns a NoOpinion, then the union authorizer moves onto the next authorizer or, if the subauthorizer was the last authorizer, returns NoOpinion as the aggregate decision

More detail at [k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/authorization/union](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/authorization/union/union.go):

```
func (authzHandler unionAuthzHandler) Authorize(a authorizer.Attributes) (authorizer.Decision, string, error) {
    var (
        errlist    []error
        reasonlist []string
    )

    for _, currAuthzHandler := range authzHandler {
        decision, reason, err := currAuthzHandler.Authorize(a)

        if err != nil {
            errlist = append(errlist, err)
        }
        if len(reason) != 0 {
            reasonlist = append(reasonlist, reason)
        }
        switch decision {
        case authorizer.DecisionAllow, authorizer.DecisionDeny:
            return decision, reason, err
        case authorizer.DecisionNoOpinion:
            // continue to the next authorizer
        }
    }

    return authorizer.DecisionNoOpinion, strings.Join(reasonlist, "\n"), utilerrors.NewAggregate(errlist)
}
```

So if you want to create your custom webhook AuthozitaionModule, if you want to pass decision to next authorizer, just give permissive response like:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "kind": "SubjectAccessReview",
  "status": {
    "reason": "no decision",
    "allowed": false,
    "denied": false
  }
}
```

Then [apiserver can make a decision by this reponse](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/plugin/pkg/authorizer/webhook/webhook.go#L208-L217):

```
    switch {
    case r.Status.Denied && r.Status.Allowed:
        return authorizer.DecisionDeny, r.Status.Reason, fmt.Errorf("webhook subject access review returned both allow and deny response")
    case r.Status.Denied:
        return authorizer.DecisionDeny, r.Status.Reason, nil
    case r.Status.Allowed:
        return authorizer.DecisionAllow, r.Status.Reason, nil
    default:
        return authorizer.DecisionNoOpinion, r.Status.Reason, nil
    }
```

Comment: This is explicitly denied by the quote in my question - "if any authorizer approves or denies a request, *that decision is immediately returned and no other authorizer is consulted*." - returning `true` as you say is the same approving the request.

Comment: That got me further. Was still not entirely clear how to apply this knowledge in a webhook context. The comment left in [SubjectAccessReviewStatus](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/74618928c25302943a3a5e903bf9a3626bc1e84a/pkg/apis/authorization/types.go#L134) finally made it click though - the answer is to provide both `"allowed": false` *and* `"denied": false` in the response. Perhaps one could deduce that simple from the `switch` above, but it wasn't immediately apparent to me that was an option. Perhaps you'd like to add that to the answer - I will accept it either way. Thanks!

Comment: Your last edit got it slightly wrong I believe. See the source code for SubjectAccessReviewStatua that I linked previously. That makes it very clear that “allowed” is non-optional. You’ll need to set both values to false to trigger the no opinion case.